# Making Balanced Teams

Tags: python, python-3.x

Very new to python and I'm trying to create a program that allows the user to:

- Enter the amount of total players
- Enter the number of teams
- Enter the name of each player
- Enter the rank of each player
- The program will then iterate through all the combinations of teams minimizing the difference of the sum of each team's total rank, while dividing up the teams with the same amount of players.
- Output should be the players of each team and the sum of their rank.

This is my code so far:

```
players = {}

print('Please enter the total amount of players:') #To enter number of players

while True:

   try:
     numPlayers = int(input())

   except ValueError:
     print('Error, please enter a number')

   else: 
     break



 print('Please enter the total number of teams: ') # to enter number of
 teams

 while True:
   try:
    numTeams = int(input())
   except ValueError:
    print('Error, please enter a number')
   else:
    break

 for i in range(numPlayers):                 # To enter each players name and rank

   k = input('Please enter players name: ')

   val = input('Please enter ' + k + "'s rank: ")

   players[k] = val
```

Basically the input gets stored in a dictionary called players and the end result looks like:

> players = {'Player 1':5, 'Player 2':4, 'Player 3': 1,.......}

I've tried to figure to this out for days but had no success, is there a python module that is able to do this?

Can someone give me a little nudge in the right direction so I know what I should be looking into.

Comment: This sounds like a slight variation of the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: Are the number of players per team fixed? Should they be dispersed evenly based on total players and number of teams? Or can you mix and match to simply attempt to find a common sum of total ranks?

Comment: There are `permutations` and `combinations` functions in the `itertools` module which should be helpful.

Comment: @Axe319 Number of players per team aren't fixed, it should be based on Total Players/ Number of teams. Also players per team should be the same for each team.

Comment: If you have 5 players with one rank 4 and the rest ones, and you want to make 2 teams, would the teams be [4], [1, 1, 1, 1] or [4, 1], [1, 1, 1]?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh [4,1],[1,1,1]